# Can walking barefoot on cold floors cause kidney problems?

Tags: infection, heat, weather, kidney-disease, barefoot

If a toddler goes barefoot most of the day on cold floors, can that lead to a kidney infection? The child is always dressed warmly but refuses to wear anything on feet.

Now being winter, and moved to a house in colder area, she constantly has a cold. Her concerned grandma always thought it was obvious that by walking on cold surfaces barefoot, chills from underfoot could enhance kidney problems?

Comment: Since this is entirely a health question, I am migrating this to our sister site about medical issues.

Comment: I really think there's no correlation between walking barefoot on cold floors and kidneys. Pls check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot#Health_implications - however, you must ensure your toddler get all the vaccines.